# How to get objects of specific type from a List of objects

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have a collection which stores multiple object types, a Textbox and a Textblock, which i am declaring like this:

```
List<object> textBoxCollection= new List<object>();
```

However, when i run a foreach loop looking just for the Textbox object, it throws an invalidcastexception.  My assuption of the foreach loop is that it would only run the operation on the object type i have called out.  Where am i going wrong?  Heres my loop:

```
foreach (MyTextBox mtb in textBoxCollection)
{

    int number
    bool mybool = Int32.TryParse(mtb.Text, out number);

    if (mybool == false)
    {
        //some operation
    }
    else
    {
        //some other operation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to narrow down the enumeration to only the correct type using [`OfType<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
foreach (MyTextBox mtb in textBoxCollection.OfType<MyTextBox>())
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check object type using [`is`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) statement:

```
    foreach (object tmp in textBoxCollection)
    {

        if(tmp  is MyTextBox) {
           MyTextBox mtb = (MyTextBox )tmp;
           int number
           bool mybool = Int32.TryParse(mtb.Text, out number);

           if (mybool == false)
           {
              //some operation
           }
           else
           {

              //some other operation
           }
        }
     }
```

Or similar statement [`as`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx):

```
    foreach (object tmp in textBoxCollection)
    {
        MyTextBox mtb = tmp as MyTextBox;
        if(mtb != null) {
        .......
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use this if you want to handle all types in the `List` in different ways.